# My onResume() throws a NullPointerException

Tags: android, onresume, onpause

I am taking accelerometer readings to catch users shaking the phone.  When a user shakes the phone, I want to design it to do something.  It works fine, but I put in an onPause() method because I don't need the accelerometer detecting any shaking motions when the user isn't within the app, as that would have undesired results.  So in the onPause() I unregister the accelerometer from the SensorManager.

It was my hope that in onResume() I could re-register the SensorManager, and go about my business.  Obviously it isn't quite working that way.  I've read the documentation and, honestly, I haven't been able to figure out what is going on.

Code:

I declare global variable sensorMgr:

```
private SensorManager sensorMgr;
```

Then I register it to the accelerometer:

```
sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    // Detect if device has accelerometer
    boolean accelSupported = sensorMgr.registerListener(this,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    if (!accelSupported) {
        // No accelerometer on this device
        sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
    }
    sensorMgr.registerListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

onPause():

```
protected void onPause() {
    if (sensorMgr != null) {
        sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorMgr = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

onResume():

```
protected void onResume() {
    sensorMgr.registerListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    super.onResume();
}
```

The error:

```
05-24 14:35:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16783): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I really appreciate any help you guys can give, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add some debugging output. Is sensorMgr null? Something is.

Comment: Actually yes, it is telling me that sensorMgr is null.  Do I have to re-initialize it even though it's a global variable?

Comment: Where are you calling `sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);`?

Comment: I am calling that in my onCreate() method

Comment: You can put that code in your `onResume()`.  It gets called shortly after `onCreate()` in every instance.

Comment: Awesome thank you guys, you've been a great help, kcoppock's answer will be accepted as soon as i can do it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sensorMgr` is null when you reach `onResume()`, since you forcibly set it to null in your `onPause()` method. Reinitialize `sensorMgr` (`getSystemService(...)`)  before calling `registerListener()`.

Comment: Yes perfect thank you.  I don't know why I didn't recognize that in the first place.  Perhaps I'm looking at code for too long? haha.